# D3 - v5 update pattern on multiple text elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following code I tried to create a visualization for a market on which one buys per hour. I tried to follow v5s update pattern but it won't let me join two text different `<text>` elements. The last added join overwrites the first so 8

I've looked around but I can not find anything related to an update pattern for two of the same elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/itsahoax/gd2uew73/7/

```
                const updateCircles = () => {
                    const circles = d3.select('svg')
                        .selectAll('circle');
                    circles
                        .data(dataPoints)
                        .join('circle')
                        .attr('cx', xPosition)
                        .attr('cy', canvasHeight)
                        .attr('r', circleRadius)
                        .attr('id', (d) => d.uniqueid)
                        .attr('fill', (d) => d.color);

                    const text = d3.select('svg')
                        .selectAll('text')
                        .data(dataPoints);

                    text
                        .join()
                        .attr('x', xPosition)
                        .attr('y', canvasHeight)
                        .attr('id', (d) => d.uniqueid)
                        .text((d) => d.description);

                    text
                        .join()
                        .attr('x', xPosition)
                        .attr('y', canvasHeight + 15)
                        .attr('id', (d) => d.uniqueid)
                        .text((d) => `${d.value} KwH`);

                };
                if (update === true) {
                    updateCircles();
                } else {
                    const circles = selection.selectAll('circle')
                        .data(dataPoints, (d) => d.id);

                    const text = selection.selectAll('text')
                        .data(dataPoints);

                    circles
                        .enter().append('circle')
                        .attr('cx', xPosition)
                        .attr('cy', canvasHeight)
                        .attr('r', circleRadius)
                        .attr('id', (d) => d.uniqueid)
                        .attr('fill', (d) => d.color)
                        .merge(circles);

                    text
                        .enter().append('text')
                        .attr('x', xPosition)
                        .attr('y', canvasHeight)
                        .attr('id', (d) => d.uniqueid)
                        .merge(text)
                        .text((d) => d.description);

                    text
                        .enter().append('text')
                        .attr('x', xPosition)
                        .attr('y', canvasHeight + 15)
                        .attr('id', (d) => d.uniqueid)
                        .merge(text)
                        .text((d) => `${d.value} KwH`);
                }
            };
```

Comment: Your problem is how you're using `d3.select('svg').selectAll('text')` That's selecting every `text` element in your `svg`, the descriptions, values, and tick values on your slider. You should use classes to be more specific on your selection, eg `d3.selection('svg').selectAll('text.slider')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use an element selector if you have multiple elements with different content with the same selector (e.g `<text>`). Add them class and use `.selectAll('.className')`
There is a working example using selection.join [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h47n9tg8/).

More information about selection.join [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join).

```
// render code
        const circles = (selection, dataPoints, isUpdate) => {
            const xPosition = (d, i) => +i * 180 + 100;

            const updateCircles = (data) => {
                const circles = d3.select('svg').selectAll('.circle-area').data(data);

                circles
                  .join((enter) => {
                    enter
                      .append('circle')
                      .attr('class', 'circle-area')
                      .attr('cx', xPosition)
                      .attr('cy', canvasHeight)
                      .attr('r', circleRadius)
                      .attr('id', (d) => d.uniqueid)
                      .attr('fill', (d) => d.color);
                    }, (update) => {
                       update.attr('fill', (d) => d.color);
                    }, (exit) => {
                       exit.remove();
                    });

                const descriptionText = d3.select('svg').selectAll('.kwh-description').data(data);

                descriptionText
                    .join((enter) => {
                      enter
                        .append('text')
                        .attr('class', 'kwh-description')
                        .attr('x', xPosition)
                        .attr('y', canvasHeight)
                        .attr('id', (d) => `description-${d.uniqueid}`)
                        .text((d) => d.description);

                    }, (update) => {
                      update.text((d) => d.description);
                    }, (exit) => {
                      exit.remove();
                    });


                const valueText = d3.select('svg').selectAll('.kwh-value').data(data);

                valueText
                    .join((enter) => {
                      enter
                        .append('text')
                        .attr('class', 'kwh-value')
                        .attr('x', xPosition)
                        .attr('y', canvasHeight + 15)
                        .attr('id', (d) => `value-${d.uniqueid}`)
                        .text((d) => `${d.value} KwH`);

                    }, (update) => {
                      update.text((d) => `${d.value} KwH`);
                    }, (exit) => {
                      exit.remove();
                    });


            };

            if (isUpdate) {
                console.log(dataPoints)
                updateCircles(dataPoints);
            }

        };
```

Comment: Wow! Huge thanks, I will study the Observable article. This looks really good! :)